# What can I do about flutter's first error code about counter?

Tags: windows, flutter

I installed flutter with package, vs code and android studio in my computer and still the first code in flutter doesn't work.There are about 18 error and some of them about package.What can i do

'_RouterState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/router.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/router.dart').
package:flutter/…/widgets/router.dart:1
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'widget'.
widget.routeInformationProvider?.addListener(_handleRouteInformationProviderNotification);
^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/router.dart:600:56: Error: The getter 'widget' isn't defined for the class '_RouterState'.

- '_RouterState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/router.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/router.dart').
  package:flutter/…/widgets/router.dart:1
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'widget'.

Comment: post the result of running flutter doctor

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run `flutter pub get` on your project! I'm not sure about Android Studio, but the `pubspec.yaml` file is the one where this is configured.

Comment: i did but still it doesn't working.I think my pubspec.yaml file is incomplate how can i complete if it is?

Comment: and also doctor flutter says that install cmaker latest version altough it is installed. i got stuck can you help me?

Comment: If you think the `pubspec.yaml` file is incomplete, you can just run `flutter create .` inside this project on the command line or even one folder above if you say this project name is to replace the ".". About the second part, I'm not sure how to help besides trying to install with Visual Studio but try to run on the browser first to see if the project runs.